# Google Custom Search API curl trouble

Tags: api, search

I'm a newbie at stackoverflow so please be patient with me :)

I'm trying to get access with the Google Custom Search API.
But I get return that I can't understand.

My query is like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?&key=********&q=red%2Bsox&cx=**********&start=0&num=10&cr=countryCA&lr=lang_fr&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd
```

And the result I get is this?

```
string '{"error": {"errors": [{"domain": "global","reason": "invalid","message": "Invalid Value"}],"code": 400,"message": "Invalid Value"}}' (length=172)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I want the result from Google to appear.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did and of the answers help?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have a cx.
Take a look at this [answer](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/vArksJWhJTM)
What happens is because this api is used mostly for adding a search option
for your site you have to specify you custom search engine (e.g. search only your site).
When you want this to search the web by code you need to do the above. Add a fake
site (where you would add your search textbox), configure it (search the web, or your site, or whatever else) and then delete the fake site

**Update**

Oh god, i just saw that. Sorry. Well the problem is that you start with 0. Valid is 1. Change start=0 with start=1 and i think you would be good to go. Take a look at this for valid values for the start parameter [official page](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have an cx.

Comment: Oh god, i just saw that. Sorry. Well the problem is that you start with 0. Valid is 1. Change start=0 with start=1 and i think you would be good to go. Take a look at this for valid values for the start parameter https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest

Comment: I am having the same issue and this did not solve my problem. I had this as my query:
(remove spaces)
h ttps:/ /w ww.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=KEY_GOES_HERE&cx=CX_GOES_HERE&q=contacts&alt=json

Same invalid value response :(

Comment: I've tried your url with my own key and cx and it works perfectly.